# Multiple records from Uploaded CSV file, returns one array only

Tags: php, mysql

Need some help.
I'm uploading a CSV file with multiple records/rows and want to insert it to database using php and mysql.
Please take a look on csv.
[image]

As you can see,there are three records which i want to be fetched and insert on my table.

However, when i uplaoded this file,it only returns a single array.
This is the return:

```
["1","1","1234","12\/1\/2017\r2","2","5678","12\/25\/2018\r3","3","13323","1\/1\/2020"]
```

Can anybody help me?
Here is my code:

```
 if(isset($_POST["Import"])){

        $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];      


         if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
           {
            $file = fopen($filename, "r");
            while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
             {

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO cardtbl    (cardid,cardno,cardpin,expdate,datecreated) 
                    VALUES     ('".$getData[0]."','".$getData[1]."','".$getData[2]."','".$getData[3]."','".$today."')";
                   // $result = mysql_query($sql);

                if(!isset($result))
                {
                    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
                            <!--window.location = \"cardlist.php\"-->
                          </script>";       
                }
                else {
                      echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
                        window.location = \"cardlist.php\"
                    </script>";
                }
             }//end

             fclose($file); 
         }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "csv_file_path"
INTO TABLE table_name
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

You can use above SQL query to insert into a table if you don't want to do any operations on the data. You can take out "IGNORE 1 LINES" string from the query if your file does not have a header. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though PHP isn't able to detect the line ending properly, it is expecting `\n` and the CSV file has `\r` file endings (as can be seen from 12/1/2017 **\r** 2).

According to the php documentation https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php you should enable `auto_detect_line_endings` by using `ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);` at the top of the file

Comment: I included it, but it returns additional blank record: ["1","1","1234","12\/1\/2017"]["2","2","5678","12\/25\/2018"]["3","3","13323","1\/1\/2020"][null]

Comment: What is the exact output you are looking for as it is now in multiple arrays rather than a large single one? The additional array at the end `[null]` is likely due to the file have an additional line at the end